# how to give country short and state short names in gem 'carmen-rails', '~> 1.0.0'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have given this in my view:

```
<div class="input-control select country_input" data-role="input-control">
      <%= f.select :country, region_options_for_select(only_us_and_france),:prompt => 'Select Country' %>
</div>               
<div class="input-control select state_input" data-role="input-control">
          <%= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country} %>
 </div>
```

and in my subregion partial this:

```
<div id="account_state_code_wrapper" >
  <% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %>
  <% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %>

  <% if country.nil? %>
      <div style="display: none">State</div>
  <% elsif country.subregions? %>
      <%= subregion_select(:account_detail, :state_code, parent_region) %>
  <% else %>
      <%= text_field(:account_detail, :state_code) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and in my helper its :

```
 def only_us_and_france
    Carmen::Country.all.select{|c| %w{US FR}.include?(c.code)}
  end
```

So its showing the name of countries and states but I want to show in my select option like US and FR  so on for state also. 
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need a hash (or two, one for states, one for countries) to match, like `{ 'France' => 'FR', 'United States' => 'US' }` etc.

Comment: Where you have defined `only_us_and_france`? You should fetch country codes there. Can you show `only_us_and_france` definition?

Comment: check if it works like this:
def only_us_and_canada
  countries = Carmen::Country.all.select{|c| %w{US CA}.include?(c.code)}
  countries.each{ |c| c.alpha_2_code}
end

Comment: this is not working:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Add new Helper method called `region_options_us_and_france` :

```
def region_options_us_and_france
    Carmen::Country.all.select{|c| %w{US FR}.include?(c.code)}.map { |r| [r.code, r.code] }
end

def sub_region_options(region)
   region.subregions.map { |r| [r.code, r.code] }
end
```

And update view :

```
<div class="input-control select country_input" data-role="input-control">
      <%= f.select :country, region_options_us_and_france, :prompt => 'Select Country' %>
</div>
```

change in 'subregion partial'

```
<%= subregion_select(:account_detail, :state_code, parent_region) %>
```

with

```
 <%= f.select :your_field_attr, sub_region_options(country), :prompt => 'Select Sub region' %>
```

Comment: Yeah it works for countries but not for subregions.i.e for states .